# PHP issue with namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

this is my example project's catalog structure:

```
htdocs/ <- xampp catalog
  project/ <- projest
    index.php <-- starter file, here I'm running engine cass
    server/
      Engine.php <- engine of routing, requesting and other
      Controller.php <- main controller class
      configs/
        autoload.php <- incuded in index.php, it makes `require_once` for all controllers, models and tolls file
        configuration.php
      controllers/
        aController.php <- extensions of main controller class.
        bController.php
      models/
        aModel.php
        bModel.php
      tools/
        aToll.php
        bToll.php
```

I set following:

for **Engine.php** - `namespace server;`

for **Controller.php** - `namespace server;`

for **aController.php** - `namespace controlls;` *(or maybe I should type `server\controllers`?)* and `use server;` because class `aController` extends class `Controller`. But code `class aController extends Controller` puts

Fatal error: Class 'server\controllers\Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\server\controllers\aController.php on line 7

It works when I adding `server` namespace and code is `class aController extends server\Controller`

How to not using `namespace` by `classname` but in `use` section?

```
namespace controllers;
use server;

class aController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }  
}
```

This code doesn't look messy, but when next i'm using static methods from and for each class using `$this->tool = new server\tools\aTool();` will make code ugly and unclear. How changes I need to do to use short and simply classes name in code for diffrent namespaces? Is this possible?

Comment: `or maybe I should type server\controllers` - yes.

Comment: You don't use the `use` syntax to include a namespace. You need to give it the full namespace AND classname.